# Were saidar and saidin influenced by the sides of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-wheel-of-time, inspiration, robert-jordan

The concepts are pretty similar: two sides of a fantastical power, one side sweet, yummy, and light, used by embracing it, used by a bunch of emotionless, calm, awesome <strike>robots</strike> people (Jedi/Aes Sedai); and another side, tainted, disgusting and fiery, used by a bunch of awesome mindless killers (Sith/Asha'man).

So my question is: **was the creation of *saidin* and *saidar* influenced in any way by the sides of the Force?**

Comment: As a channeller of *saidin*, I take great offence at this question.

Comment: Both Saidin and Saidar were created pure. Saidin was corrupted by the dark one when the bore was made if I remember correctly.

Comment: @randal'thor As a user of the Force, I take offence at your offence. At least I didn't call you or me a robot

Comment: @Theyna True, but RJ may have created it with one side light and one dark; this is its out-of-universe inception, not in.

Comment: @Theyna The taint on *saidin* came from the DO, but its nature was always to be fought rather than surrendered to, to be fire and ice rather than a tranquil river. And like CHEESE says, light and dark: light = Flame of Tar Valon while dark = Dragon's Fang.

Comment: @randal'thor Well said.  I would hope you would say it well--you use it.

Comment: @randal'thor I realise that Saidin needs to be pulled and fought by the channeller but the question mentions tainted and disgusting which is what my comment was referring to. Though I was not aware that the dark side also felt tainted/disgusting to dark force users.

Comment: @Theyna I can tell you it definitely does not

Comment: @Thats a relief, unfortunately my midichlorian count is not high enough to be able to use the force at all.

Comment: It seems obvious that both ideas (saidin/saidar and light side/dark side of the force) come from the ancient Chinese philosophy of yin and yang. The descriptions of the Flame of Tar Valon and Dragon's Fang are clear allusions to the taijitu (yin/yang symbol).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No.

From [an interview with Robert Jordan](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=79):

> I've noticed a bit of an influence from the Star Wars series...is there any truth to this?
>
> **Robert Jordan**: *(lol)* No. I don't read Star Wars books.

<sub>Thank *God* I don't have to honour Star Wars (in which I have no interest) as an inspiration for the great Wheel of Time!</sub>

Comment: Phew. That's a relief.

Comment: I second that, this question had me quite concerned for a little while, though I wasn't the one being accused of Sith activities.

Comment: Jordan only says "books" here, perhaps thinking that's what the interviewer was asking specifically about, that doesn't necessarily mean Jordan couldn't have been influenced by the Star Wars *movies*...

Comment: @randal'thor It is, I agree.  I mean, I dabble in the Force (who doesn't) but I started out with the One Power, since Star Wars is obviously inferior.

Answer (score 1):

They are based more on the concepts of yin and yang:
Yin, the negative, passive, female aspect
Saidar, the female half of the True Source, which is embraced, yielded to, and which cannot be forced to do anything.
Yang, the positive, active, male aspect
Saidin, the male half of the True Source, which must be seized, wielded, and coerced or it will destroy you.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that claim or is it your own speculation?